# =SUBTOTAL (9, ) formula in pandas

Tags: excel, pandas

I have Just finished editing some excel files and was wondering if there is a way of adding the equivalent =Subtotal(9 ) in pandas.

I've used df.loc["Total", "ProfitLoss"] = df.ProfitLoss.sum()

which does add up, the total profitLoss Column. But when it goes back to excel the total doesn't change when I start using filters like it does with =subtotal(9 )

Comment: Skip using pandas and write a `SUBTOTAL` formula using openpyxl.

Comment: Just here to second what @BigBen said. Using pandas you are simply writing the value but you need to write a formula which isn't something you can do with pandas